# SMPlayer 17.12.0 has no sound with any output driver

Tags: 16.04, smplayer

This question is very similar to [SMPlayer has no sound with any output driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960883/smplayer-has-no-sound-with-any-output-driver), but no solution from there is working. Also I have more recent versions: `mpv 0.28.0` and `SMPlayer 17.12.0`.

Sound in `mpv` alone is working, but there is no sound for every single output options in `smplayer`. I don't even see the application in `pavucontrol`, it seems like the audio is diabled in SMPlayer somehow, or incompatible with some mpv option. VLC and MPV players are working fine (sound is present, can be redirected to any device in pavucontrol tool).

Any idea how to fix this or how to downgrade to previous package versions which were working (at least the sound, now it is totally unusable)?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064230/707129/). I gave an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is totally different to the [SMPlayer has no sound with any output driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960883/smplayer-has-no-sound-with-any-output-driver) question. In my case I was using an internal pan audio filter like this (custom arguments for mpv):

```
--af=pan=6:[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
```

But the internal pan audio filter was removed and now is used an external one which has totally different syntax - https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan-1. After removing custom arguments for mpv sound is working, now I have to rewrite it to new syntax.